# Find an example of a non-cyclic abelian group of permutations with n^2 elements for each n in the natural numbers, n >3.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, abelian-groups, symmetric-groups

I'm really stuck on this problem below from my textbook:

**Find an example of a non-cyclic abelian group of permutations with $n^2$ elements for each n in the natural numbers, $n > 3$.**

It seems quite vague, and I'm not really sure where to begin. If anyone could help, I would be very appreciative.

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: For $n=4$, I take $G=\langle (1234) \rangle \times \langle (5678) \rangle$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $$G=\langle (12\dots n)\rangle\times \langle(n+1 \dots 2n)\rangle=H\times K$$
Note that $|H|=|K|=n$, hence $G$ is not cyclic.
Since $H,K$ are abelian, so is $G$.
Also $|G|=|H||K|=n^2$.

Comment: Your second permutation should run to 2n

Comment: Thank you very much! Should the first permutation start 1,2 as opposed to 12? Just checking! Also what does it mean to "multiply" two groups together? I haven't met that notation yet. Is it the Cartesian product? If so what's an example of an element in G? Thanks Alan.

Comment: @aPaulT Editted. Thanks!

Comment: @Jack The first permutation is $(1,2,\dots,n)$ while the second permutation is $(n+1,\dots,2n)$. This type of group is called direct product. This group can be also written as $G=\{(1,2,\dots,n)^a(n+1,\dots,2n)^b\;|\;0\leq a,b\leq n-1\}$.

Comment: @AlanWang Thanks - helpful explanation.

Comment: It might be clearer to describe these examples as $\mathbb{Z}_n\times\mathbb{Z}_n$.  Every finite group is a group of permutations.

Comment: How come $|H| = |K| = n$ implies the group isn't cyclic?

Comment: @Jack $\Bbb{Z}_a \times \Bbb{Z}_b$ is cyclic iff $a$ and $b$ are coprime.